# How to get the weekday of a day in ubuntu terminal

Tags: linux, date, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

How do I get the weekday from a date in the ubuntu terminal?

For example I type in: `1990-01-22`, I want to get an output that says for example `Thursday if 22th day was a thursday`.

Answer (score 9):

Use `%A`:

```
$ date -d"1990-01-22" "+%A"
Monday
```

From `man date`:

```
   %A     locale's full weekday name (e.g., Sunday)
```

Comment: `+%u` and `+%w` might also be of interest, for the numerical representation ranging either from 1 to 7 or from 0 to 6, respectively...

Comment: @twalberg caveat that `%w` starts the week on Sunday (`0`) whereas `%u` starts the week on Monday (`1`). So actually `%u` and `%w` give the same result on Monday - Saturday.

Comment: For me, it's return the weekday string in my home country language (Portuguese). Is there a way to force an English answer?

Comment: @ArthurHenriqueDellaFraga check https://makandracards.com/makandra/28205-linux-running-a-program-with-a-different-locale-than-your-default, the idea basically is to say `LC_ALL=<another locale> <command>`